# How can I set Duration value for a BrushTransition in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

In a `UWP` app, I'm using a simple brush animation:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.BackgroundTransition>
        <BrushTransition/>
    </Grid.BackgroundTransition>
</Grid>
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.brushtransition.duration?view=winrt-22621) I see, that it has a Duration property and I'd like to change it. I tried to set a numeric value (like this: `<BrushTransition Duration="1000"/>`), but it does not work.

So, how can I set a `TimeSpan` value in `XAML`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `Duration` is not a simple number.

It should be in this format `Duration="xx:xx:xx"`.

You can see the official usage example in [GitHub Windows-universal-samples.](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/b1cb20f191d3fd99ce89df50c5b7d1a6e2382c01/Samples/Simple3DGameXaml/cpp/DirectXPage.xaml#L28)